# Azure Functions V3 ILogger using DI - messages from logger not in traces

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, ilogger

In my Azure Function I am trying to log using the DI container; however I am unable to get the logger to display messages in the Log Stream or the Traces in Application Insights. I have created a minimal code  sample project which I am testing using the Azure Portal (Code + Test) shown here.
I've tried using Serilog same result.
I've tried removing the log parameter from Function1 - then I get no errors nor messages
I assume I'm missing something simple/obvious but I'm stuck.

```
namespace LoggingApiTest {
public class Function1 {
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        logger.LogInformation("In Function1 ctor using DI created Logger");
    }

    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "Test")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log) {
        logger.LogInformation("Hello from DI Logger");
        log.LogInformation("Hello from logger passed as parameter");
        return new OkObjectResult("Hello");
    }
}
```

}

startup

```
namespace LoggingApiTest {
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup {
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddLogging();

    }
}
```

}

host.json

```
enter code here{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
  "applicationInsights": {
    "samplingSettings": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "excludedTypes": "Request"
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

}

The LogStream shows `2021-07-16T12:59:50.705 [Information] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=b8238346-7ff7-450d-a7f0-abc8f1a210fa) 2021-07-16T12:59:50.705 [Information] Hello from logger passed as parameter 2021-07-16T12:59:50.705 [Information] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=b8238346-7ff7-450d-a7f0-abc8f1a210fa, Duration=1ms)`

Answer (score 0):

In your logging section of your `host.json` file, try adding your solution namespace with the `logLevel`. This should enable logging at a `logLevel` of `Information` and above.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "LoggingApiTest": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4425#issuecomment-492678381

Comment: I had already tried that.  I did it again just now but it had no effect

Comment: removing the applicationInsights section for host.json resulted in messages appearing application insights trace log. Yay.

Comment: it was the "excludedTypes": "Request" in applicationInsights section


{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "LoggingApiTest": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: funny thing is I got the offending line by copying it from the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Comment: @user1221237 well done on finding the fix!